# Why the text of a JOptionPane have a strange appearance in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I was recently doing a GUI when I ran a JOptionPane and text was very strange.

Does anyone know what is happening and how can I fix it?

[image: This is the Pane]

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "THIS IS A TEXT TEST");
```

Comment: That should not happen.  But I have occasionally seen strange behaviors in fonts (in many applications, not just Java), after an update is done without a reboot.  Make sure all updates are installed, then reboot.

Comment: I just installed and updated everything, apparently it's still the same.

I will look through the ubuntu forums to see someone with the same problem.